# Printing HTML templates using EPSON epos iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, uiwebview, epson

I am building cordova print plugin using EPSON epos iOS SDK, to use it with hybrid mobile apps( ionic framework based). The sdk provides methods for printing text and image. But I have to print HTML template using it. is there any way to do so?

like if I can prepare UIWebView object from the template and convert it into UIImage. I am new to iOS development so dont know any proper way of doing that.

Comment: In short, do you want to get the content of your view as an UIImage?

Comment: Yes kind of. But the problem is that the app is not pure iOS application. So is there any way to  do that inside cordova plugin's Objective C code??

Comment: I am not sure of Cordova, but as far as I know it's javascript, and you could use it to convert a div to image. Have you tried this? One example: http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/ which uses html2canvas library.

Answer (score 0):

You can render the `UIWebView` offscreen, and then capture its as a `UIImage`. the answers below might help you solve the problem. One problem you may face is that `UIWebView` doesn't loads unless you add it on a `UIWindow`, this window can be any `UIWindow` object, not necessarily the window you are displaying to user.

[How to get ENTIRE image from UIWebView including offscreen content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881442/how-to-get-entire-image-from-uiwebview-including-offscreen-content)

[Does iPhone/iPad UIWebView need to be active view to render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853805/does-iphone-ipad-uiwebview-need-to-be-active-view-to-render)

[How do I save the contents of a UIWebView as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793522/how-do-i-save-the-contents-of-a-uiwebview-as-an-image)